# Procedimientos almacenados en C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedure

Estoy programando un login en **C#** con validaciones de usuario por Procedimientos almacenados en **SQL Server**.

Estoy intentando de todo y no me da un resultado.

Quisiera saber si alguien me podria ayudar con el codigo.

```
Clase de validacion en C#:

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_ValidaUsuarioLogin_Id", conn);
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    SqlParameter rept = new SqlParameter("rept", SqlDbType.Int);
                    rept.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    command.Parameters.Add(rept);

                    SqlParameter IdUsuario = new SqlParameter("IdUsuario", SqlDbType.Int);
                    IdUsuario.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    command.Parameters.Add(IdUsuario);

                    SqlParameter NomUsuario = new SqlParameter("NomUsuario", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    NomUsuario.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    command.Parameters.Add(NomUsuario);

                    SqlParameter IdEmpresa = new SqlParameter("IdEmpresa", SqlDbType.Int);
                    IdEmpresa.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    command.Parameters.Add(IdEmpresa);

                    SqlParameter IdPais = new SqlParameter("IdPais", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    IdPais.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    command.Parameters.Add(IdPais);

                    SqlParameter Pais = new SqlParameter("Pais", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    Pais.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    command.Parameters.Add(Pais);

                    SqlParameter CodPais = new SqlParameter("CodPais", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    CodPais.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    command.Parameters.Add(CodPais);

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Usuario", mail);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("PassUsuario", password);

                    int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    var r = rowsAffected;
                    return Convert.ToInt32(command.Parameters["IdUsuario"].Value);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                    return 5;
                }
```

y el Procedimiento almacenado en SQL es:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ValidaUsuarioLogin_Id]
(
@Usuario  varchar(200),
@PassUsuario varchar(100),
@rept int output,
@IdUsuario int output,
@NomUsuario  varchar(300) output,
@IdEmpresa int output,
@IdPais varchar(6) output,
@Pais varchar(200) output,
@CodPais int output
)
as

declare @verifica int,
        @valusuario int

set @verifica   = (select count(*) from Usuario where email = @Usuario and estado = 'A' and claveHash =HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @PassUsuario ) )
set @valusuario = (select count(*) from Usuario where email = @Usuario and estado = 'A')

if @verifica > 0
    begin
       set @rept = 1

       Select @IdUsuario=u.id_usuario,@NomUsuario=u.email,@IdEmpresa=e.id_Empresa,@IdPais=e.id_pais,@Pais=UPPER(p.nombre)
       From Usuario u
       Inner Join Empresa e On u.id_usuario=e.id_usuario
       Inner Join Pais p On e.id_pais=p.id_pais And p.id_idioma='ES'
       where u.email = @Usuario and u.estado = 'A' and u.claveHash =HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @PassUsuario )

       Select @CodPais=id_grupo From GrupoCab Where nombre_corto=@IdPais And activo=1

    end
else
    begin
        if @valusuario > 0
            begin
            set @rept = 2
            set @IdUsuario=0
            set @NomUsuario = ''
            set @IdEmpresa=0
            set @IdPais=''
            set @Pais=''
            Set @CodPais=0
            end
        else
            begin
            set @rept = 0
            set @IdUsuario=0
            set @NomUsuario = ''
            set @IdEmpresa=0
            set @IdPais=''
            set @Pais=''
            Set @CodPais=0
        end
    end
```

[**Procedimiento almacenado**](https://hastebin.com/devikiqafi.sql)

[**Clase en C#**](https://hastebin.com/etexugafiz.cs)

Comment: No tengo experiencia con SQL server, pero me imagino que el error se debe a que no estás retornando nada. Te falta un return @variable

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual es el error o problema que estas recibiendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya probaste el procedimiento almacenado dentro de SQL ?

Algo con lo que me he encontrado en ocasiones es que incluso si los parametros estan nombrados correctamente, si no los agregas en el mismo orden a los parameters la llamada al procedure falla.

también el type de "add" que uses afecta, para los input yo suelo irme con la sobrecarga de add donde indicas el tipo de dato y luego agrego el value, en una sola linea queda algo asi :

```
 comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@para1", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = "ParametrodeEntrada";
```

Que resultados estas obteniendo del store procedure cuando lo llamas desde c#?

Comment: Si encontre cual era el error en la linea
SqlParameter IdPais = new SqlParameter("IdPais", SqlDbType.VarChar);
No le estaba dando el tamaño a el tipo de dato de salida que estaba enviando
Y en el sql si me ejecutaba el procedimiento almacenado pero no retornaba la variable de salida le agregue una linea mas que jhaga un select a la variable que queria y con el executescalar lo obtuve en mi consulta c#